# How to solve no module error when testing the code?

Tags: django, pytest

I faced the error  `No module named 'rest_framework'` when testing the code, however rest_framework is installed and everything works just fine. The problem occurs only on tests. When I run `pip3 install djangorestframework` or `python -m pip install djangorestframework` , I get this `Requirement already satisfied:`  Everything what I found in the internet did not help. Also I have the following error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You`

Comment: Do you run the tests in a different virtual environment? Did you *activate* the environment before running tests?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem run tests in the same directory as when I run the server

Comment: that does not matter. Did you activate the virtual environment before running the tests.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is already activated. before the directory I have (venv)